# Que tags indicar quando se pretende ver uma solução em várias linguagens

Tags: debate, suporte

Gostaria de saber o que/como devo fazer quando pretendo obter uma solução implementada em diversas linguagens de programação (se questões do gênero forem permissíveis)?

**Exemplo:**

*Gostaria de saber como acrescentar um dia à uma data em diversas linguagens de programação?*

Se for permitido, qual(quais) `tags` podem/devem ser utilizadas?

Comment: Que eu saiba, [tag:independente-de-linguagem]

Comment: Nem havia experimentado ainda escrever nada, muito obrigado @brasofilo

Comment: Acho bom comentar que uma pergunta tal como seu exemplo provavelmente seria mal recebida na comunidade. Ver ['Como podemos lidar com as "listas"'](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/819/215) para mais detalhes. Muito embora [eu próprio seja a favor de listas observados certos cuidados](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/841/215), a posição atual da comunidade é que isso não deve ser feito - em vez disso você deve abrir uma pergunta separada pra cada linguagem em que está interessado (e eu concordo com isso). Acho até que a tag `independente-de-linguagem` talvez pudesse ser removida.